# How to prepare all urls for a transfer from: Domain/ftpfolder/page to domain2/page?

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink, href, portfolio

Right now I'm bulding a wordpress website on my server. Urls are `http://domain.com/ftpfolder/page`
Problem that I have is that I'm going to have to transfer this website to the client's server and links will be like this `http://domain2.com/page`

Wordpress Address & Site URL can fix this easily, however, not all links in the website will be changed as some of them are entered manually. I did the test already.

My question is: How do I write all images/pages links in order to be ready for the transfer?

I thought I could name all of them `<a href="./page">` but this creates mistakes for some links.

For eg. I have to some images in a page called "expertise": `http://domain.com/ftpfolder/expertise`

I want each image to link to a specific product (wordpress portfolio), for example: `http://domain.com/ftpfolder/portfolio/product1` 
If I use `<a href="./portfolio/products1">`, then the link becomes:
 `http://domain2.com/expertise/portfolio/product1` which doesn't work because /expertise/portfolio doesn't exist as mentioned two lines above (because I'm using wordpress pages and portfolios, so categories are bypassed)

So should I write all my links: http://domain.com/ftpfolder/... and then replace this by http://domain2.com/... in the database? If yes, how do I do it?
Or is there another technique I'm not aware of to simplify my links? 
 Or should I rethink the way my content is organised, but I'm not sure how.

Hope this makes sense, sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "[Search and Replace Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/comment-page-36/)" as advised by the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs).

Use to replace 1 with 2:

1. `domain.com/ftpfolder/page`
2. `domain2.com/page`

Oh, did I tell you to do a backup first?

Comment: Cheers Nabil. So it has to be complete links everywhere.
Is is the best solution, or should I move now the whole website to a subdomain, instead of an ftpfolder? Thanks a lot

Comment: The script "Search and Replace" is your best bet, just be sure you don't use relative URLs like you said in the OP.

Comment: Ok. Another one, sorry. 
If I dig in the db, I have a lot of "params" written this way 
"http:\/\/domain.com\/ftpfolder\/wp-content\/uploads\/broadcast-concert.jpg"
I tried replacing domain.com\/ftpfolder by domain2.com but I get a MySQL error #1064, any idea?

Comment: You should not do a normal search and replace on the database.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late feedback. Just to let you know I was able to achieve this with this script https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases following your suggestions.
Sorry I can't vote you up yet. Thanks again for your help.